# GC Survivor Space Full

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-kafka

I have a connector (Kafka-connect) streaming data from kafka to some other system. After processing 60 000 + records, it slows down dramatically to the point that I actually end up killing my connector.

I looked at GC with the jmap command and it seems that only my Survivor Space is full (100% used).

How can this be ? isn't the Survivor Space only a temporary place ? As I understood from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535396/g1-garbage-collector-why-survivor-space-is-always-full%20this)

What I can not understand is the fact that it processes 60 000 records before fully using the Survivor Space. Why doesn't this happen before ? Shouldn't he free this space by putting a part of it to the Old Gen ?

Btw: I am runnin this connector in standalone mode, with 256MB for the heap (107 for Eden + 1 for survivor + 95 for Old)

Here is a sample jmap

```
Heap Configuration:

MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
MaxHeapSize              = 268435456 (256.0MB)
NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
MaxNewSize               = 160432128 (153.0MB)
OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
NewRatio                 = 2
SurvivorRatio            = 8
MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
G1HeapRegionSize         = 1048576 (1.0MB) 

Heap Usage:

G1 Heap:
regions  = 256
capacity = 268435456 (256.0MB)
used     = 130770392 (124.71236419677734MB)
free     = 137665064 (131.28763580322266MB)
48.71576726436615% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
regions  = 107
capacity = 167772160 (160.0MB)
used     = 112197632 (107.0MB)
free     = 55574528 (53.0MB)
66.875% used
Survivor Space:
regions  = 1
capacity = 1048576 (1.0MB)
used     = 1048576 (1.0MB)
free     = 0 (0.0MB)
100.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
regions  = 18
capacity = 99614720 (95.0MB)
used     = 17524184 (16.712364196777344MB)
free     = 82090536 (78.28763580322266MB)
17.591962312397204% used`
```

Comment: Which JDK?  Hopefully you'll say version 8 or higher.  From Oracle, IBM, OpenJVM, or somewhere else?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know which OS you're running on.

Comment: There is a leap in your reasoning. Why do you think that the slowdown is related to that specific GC stat? You should enable GC logging or jstat to see how much time it actually spends GCing

Comment: JDK 1.8, Redhat 7.2 x86_64.  I do agree that it might not be related to GC then but what could it be (I had OOM before I fixed a bug)? I am doing stateless operations, basically reading and putting records. What could go wrong ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was done by another application doing buffering. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're saying "it slows down dramatically" but you didn't do even basic stat gathering, e.g. whether it's pegged at 100% CPU or bottlenecked on some other resource.

Assuming it is consuming CPU time the next step is to identify whether it's spent in GC or in application code. GC logs and running jstack and jstat or a profiler will help there. Mitigation will depend on those findings.

Survivor spaces being full after a GC is unusual, but since you are doing stream-processing the allocated objects might be short-lived enough that objects simply don't survive long enough to make it out of eden space. Without more information it is hard to tell whether it's a problem or not.

Comment: I did look at top. The cpu is not a problem. I finally found that it was some library doing internal buffering. Thanks anyway :)